# DLL load failed during tensorflow import

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Im trying to import tensorflow in Python3.6.
But i keep getting this log:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Python36_64\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Python36_64\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Does anyone have an idea whats happening?

Comment: How did you install tensorflow?